# Is using POSIX pipes/sockets for IPC memory-safe?

Tags: ipc

As far as I can tell, IPC through shared memory is fastest, but the drawback is that when one process introduces memory corruption (stack/heap corruption due to programming errors) then all bets are off and all processes accessing it might get affected.

What is the situation with IPC using sockets or named pipes? If a corrupted process communicates with healthy processes through pipes/sockets, can other processes also get affected, or is there some kind of data validation in place? For example, would passing an open file descriptor to a potentially corrupted process be safer than using shared files/memory?

Comment: Why would communicating via IPC be different to communicating via files, sockets, or network in this regard?